# The second-order correlation function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, quantum-optics, correlation-functions

The second order correlation function for a single mode EM is:

$$g^{\left(2\right)}\left(\tau = 0\right)=\frac{\left\langle \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{a}\right\rangle }{\left\langle \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\right\rangle ^{2}}$$
as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_antibunching) for example. My question is then, shouldn't it be valid for **any** $\tau$ and not just for $\tau=0$?  Since $$\begin{cases}
\hat{a}\left(t\right)=e^{-i\omega t}\hat{a}\\
\hat{a}^{\dagger}\left(t\right)=e^{i\omega t}\hat{a}^{\dagger}
\end{cases}$$ so the phases cancel out.

Comment: The assumption about the temporal evolution is only valid for a free monochromatic theory. In general the situation can be much more complicated.

Comment: For the arbitrary moment $\tau$ the second-order correlation function has a form 
$$
g^{(2)}(\tau) = \frac{ \langle a^\dagger (t) a^\dagger (t + \tau) a(t+\tau)a(t) \rangle}{\langle a^\dagger (t) a(t)  \rangle^2  },
$$
see https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/optical-coherence-and-quantum-optics/F8CB94C70FA64CD3FB60890CA2048168